# Codeigniter Jquery Ajax request error on URL localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i'm using Codeigniter 3.11, php 7.4, and jquery 3.5.1. Recently, i create a rest API using restserver in Codeigniter. And this rest server will be hosted once finished. Below is the code for controller in the server:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use chriskacerguis\RestServer\RestController;

class Genre extends RestController
{

    private const PATH_MODEL = 'Genre_model';
    private const PARAM_CATEGORY = 'c';
    private const PARAM_LIMIT = 'l';
    private const PARAM_GROUPED = 'g';
    private const PARAM_STATUS = 'status';
    private const PARAM_MESSAGE = 'messages';
    private const PARAM_RESULT = 'result';
    private const STATUS_OK = 'ok';
    private const STATUS_ERROR = 'error';


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model($this::PATH_MODEL, 'genre');
    }

    public function index_get()
    {
        $limit = (isset($_GET[$this::PARAM_LIMIT])) ? (int) $_GET[$this::PARAM_LIMIT] : 0;
        $isGrouped = (isset($_GET[$this::PARAM_GROUPED])) ? (int)($_GET[$this::PARAM_GROUPED]) : false;

        $this->response(
            array(
                $this::PARAM_STATUS => $this::STATUS_OK,
                $this::PARAM_MESSAGE => 'success get data.',
                $this::PARAM_RESULT => $this->genre->getGenre($limit, $isGrouped)
            ),
            RestController::HTTP_OK
        );
    }

}
?>
```

And this is the code for client:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    var settings = {
        "url": "localhost/local-api/v1/genre?g=1&l=5",
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        },
        "method": "GET",
        "timeout": 0,
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="btn">Click me</button>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm getting this error when i want to request to localhost using jquery ajax.

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2 GET http://localhost/local-api/localhost/local-api/v1/genre?g=1&l=5 404 (Not Found)
```

Can anyone explain why the link get duplicated? and how to solve it? thank you for your interest.

Comment: Try to add the protocol to begining of the URL: `"url": "http://localhost/local-api/v1/genre?g=1&l=5",`

Comment: Thank you very much. i didn't realize just add http will solve it.